# Are /dev/{udp,tcp} standardized or available everywhere?

Tags: devices, tcp, udp, portability

I've recently learned about the `/dev/udp` and `/dev/tcp` pseudo-devices [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/devref1.html). Are they specific to some GNU/Linux distributions or can I find them on other unix systems?

Are they standardized in some way?

So far, I've been able to use them successfuly on OS X, Arch Linux and CentOS.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is a feature of the *shell* and not the operating system.

So, for example,on Solaris 10 with `ksh88` as the shell:

```
% cat < /dev/tcp/localhost/22
ksh: /dev/tcp/localhost/22: cannot open
```

However if we switch to `bash`:

```
% bash
bash-3.2$ cat < /dev/tcp/localhost/22
SSH-2.0-Sun_SSH_1.1.5
```

So `bash` interprets the `/dev/tcp` but ksh88 didn't.

On Solaris 11 with `ksh93` as the shell:

```
% cat < /dev/tcp/localhost/22
SSH-2.0-Sun_SSH_2.2
```

So we can see it's very dependent on the shell in use.

Comment: Also depends on compile-time options -- not all bash builds will have it enabled.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy True enough; also true of ksh (ksh-88 tried to autodetect, but I'm not sure it worked properly).

Comment: Regarding the first sentence, [POSIX does standardize some basic shell features](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html) (although `/dev/tcp/...` isn't one of them).

Answer (score 5):

To add on, from [the Bash Info node](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html):

> Bash handles several filenames specially when they are used in
>   redirections, as described in the following table.  If the operating
>   system on which Bash is running provides these special files, bash
>   will use them; otherwise it will emulate them internally with the
>   behavior described below.
>
> '/dev/fd/FD'
>        If FD is a valid integer, file descriptor FD is duplicated.
>
> '/dev/stdin'
>        File descriptor 0 is duplicated.
>
> '/dev/stdout'
>        File descriptor 1 is duplicated.
>
> '/dev/stderr'
>        File descriptor 2 is duplicated.
>
> '/dev/tcp/HOST/PORT'
>        If HOST is a valid hostname or Internet address, and PORT is an
>        integer port number or service name, Bash attempts to open the
>        corresponding TCP socket.
>
> '/dev/udp/HOST/PORT'
>        If HOST is a valid hostname or Internet address, and PORT is an
>        integer port number or service name, Bash attempts to open the
>        corresponding UDP socket.