stdin redirection from /dev/tcp/localhost/port
I'm trying to get my head around some TCP-related topics, and have been experimenting:
The following works fine:
Process A: nc -l 12345 | wc -c
Process B: </dev/random head -c 1k > /dev/tcp/localhost/12345
But this doesn't:
Process A:
wc -c < /dev/tcp/localhost/12345
bash: connect: Connection refused
bash: /dev/tcp/localhost/12345: Connection refused

If I could redirect data to a port on /dev/tcp, why can't I redirect from it?

Because there's nothing you connect to! Opening /dev/tcp/{HOST}/{PORT} tells bash to establish a TCP connection to HOST:PORT. So, in your case, no matter which direction the data flows, the server (your nc -l {PORT}) needs to run first.
I'll be honest: stick with nc; while a really cute idea, bash's TCP filesystem emulation (you're on Linux; unlike, say, Plan9, there's no /dev/tcp/, actually! Try ls -ld /dev/tcp ;) ) has enough hard-to-catch corner cases that I'd say you're probably better off that way, unless you really want to get an opened and connected socket as stdin or stdout (or rarely, stderr) file descriptors of your program. (nc could open such a socket and replace its stdout with it using freopen, but it doesn't.)
If you want learn about TCP, I don't think the comfort of your shell is the right place; pick up the "proper" programming language of your choice (be it C, Python, Perl, …) and open sockets, send data, learn first hand how much fragmentation is terrible, and so on.

Thanks for the advice. I've just measured and found out that piping to nc is faster than redirecting to /dev/tcp - I expected /dev/tcp to be faster but hadn't realised that that's something that was emulated by Bash.

the emulation isn't what makes it slow; it's the fact that this emulation hands through the open socket to a program that has no idea that writes of a certain size are going to be split or cause very small (and thus very many) packets to be transferred. Note that loopback speed tests on modern Linuxes are complicated: When you run with iperf3 from localhost to localhost, chances are you get lower performance than if you do the same between two containers using the macvlan virtual network emulation layer. I honestly don't know why.

The availability may also depend on how bash was compiled; see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/311099/168757 .  It's not necessarily portable, so I'd avoid it.
